# Youtube, can I get data of user when they login with Google OpenID?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I want to get data about favourist list, another list or another playlist of Youtube default  when user login with OpenID in my website, And I read YoutubeAPI but I don't find any place talk about this. But I see `Jasmine` (this is an app on iphone - it's like app Youtube) can get data of user when they login with Google OpenID. `How can I do the same thing with Jasmine`. Anybody, can show me some orientation to resolve this trouble. 
Thank you so much,

Comment: Are you sure this is about Yii? It sounds like a very general question.

Comment: @Narretz: Oh thank you, This's my careless and  I edited my question

Comment: I answered this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662127